# What is contacts.edb structure?

Tags: parsing, data-structures, msn-messenger

Windows Live Messenger creates a number of files like

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Contacts{ae86acef-5a45-4447-bc32-521fc9289e1a}\DBStore\contacts.edb

and stores contacts within. When looking on such files, it is obviouos that they have strict structure. However, I failed to find the description of contacts.edb structure in internet.

Does anybody knows this structure? Or maybe there are some parser sources available? (I do not need a exe for that, I know about NirSoft one).

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [`libesedb`](https://code.google.com/p/libesedb/) which might be of use here.
The `contacts.edb` file is an ESEBD file.